# Copycopter-server : bundle install failed due to "Platform" gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, copycopter

I have decided to try to deploy [Copycopter-server](http://railscasts.com/episodes/336-copycopter?view=asciicast) on my VPS . After cloning the Github repository on my development machine , I tried `bundle install` . And then the error appeared :

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/gems/Platform-0.4.0.gem)
```

I have tried to install the gems `Platform` and `Popen4` locally with no success . It seems the [last activity](http://rubygems.org/gems/Platform) for improvement of the `Platform` gem is from 2005...

I need your advices on :

- how can I find where these gems (`Platforma` is a dependency of `Popen4`) are used in the `Copycopter-server` application ?
- Could it be a temporary Rubigems.org problem or the gems are not compatible with Rails 3.2.11 ?
- What could be the reason the names  `Platform` and `Popen4` to be capitalized in the Gemfile?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your network settings. Connection refused sounds more like your are not allowed to connect to rubygems at all. Try a

```
curl "http://rubygems.org"
```

to find out.

Update from the comments:

The source line in the `Gemfile` has to be changed from

```
source :rubygems
```

to

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: `curl` works OK. Is this line on top of `Gemfile` looks fine :`source :rubygems` ?

Comment: Thank you for your help . It seems the `source :rubygems` (on the top of Gemfile) was incorrect . It should be : `source 'https://rubygems.org' ` . Please , add it to your answer .

Comment: Done. Glad that it put you into the right direction at least.